# Не пойму почему не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

Нужен бот который будет нажимать на кнопку сообщения в телеграмме.

Написано было быстро, но почему-то не работает. Замучался искать ошибку

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events, functions


api_id = 
api_hash = ''

client = TelegramClient('ses', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('название чата')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    await event.message.click(i=0)

client.start()

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

В чём ошибка? Можете подсказать как это наладить?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: Вы присваивали значение переменным `app_id` и `app_hash` ?